Random Number Generator with criteria
I am trying to generate random numbers in a range of 1 - 25 for 7 columns and the last column needs to have a range of 1 - 10
This is how I'm generating my random numbers.
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%25 + 1 AS Number1
    ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%25 + 1 AS Number2
    ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%25 + 1 AS Number3
    ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%25 + 1 AS Number4
    ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%25 + 1 AS Number5
    ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%25 + 1 AS Number6
    ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%25 + 1 AS Number7
    ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10 + 1 AS Number8 FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 1000000);

I was thinking to put the generation in a cursor so that after it generates 1 number set it will go through checks like
eg.
are any of the numbers repeating?
are any number sets the same?
and if it passes the check it will insert it into the table
also column 8 can have the same number that appears in columns 1 - 7 but columns 1 - 7 can't have the same number in that same number set.
The only issue I am having is how to incorporate the checks into the generation of the number sets, I assumed a cursor will be the best as it will run through the cursor each time for each number set that is generated and thus when it has generated all possible number sets it will just end.

Is there a reason that you don't want to use the random number generator built into SQL server? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql

@tgolisch i'm guessing cause it usually generates same value for every row

Per the MS docs "If seed isn't specified, the SQL Server Database Engine assigns a seed value at random. For a specified seed value, the result returned is always the same.". So, don't use a seed.

If you are using this in a cursor, the values should seem random

... unless this is used for something that needs to be "very random" and not just ordinary random. eg. security key or gambling programs

"Columns 1 - 7 can't have the same number in that same number set" - Does this mean that you want to allow sets like {1, 2, 3, ...} and {3, 2, 1, ...}, but not {3, 1, 3, ...}?  "I assumed a cursor will be the best" - Can you clarify how you plan on using the cursor?

Side note: Your current expression ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5 has a very very slight (1 in 2^32) chance of causing an Arithmetic overflow at the ABS() step. Applying ABS() after the modulo would avoid this - ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 5)

If you want to avoid repeating numbers, then you aren't really using random numbers...

@HardCode I'm imagining a situation like lottery numbers where you wouldn't be allowed to play the same number twice in a line

@MartinSmith I see, then the OP is really asking for a "random draw from a set of numbers".

As I understand your question, you need to randomly generate distinct Number1 .. Number7 values from the range 1..25, while the Number8 selection is independent.
You can do this by using a CROSS APPLY to:

Generate the values 1..25.
Associate random values to each.
Use the ROW_NUMBER() window function to define the permutated order.
Use conditional aggregation to select the final values in your result.

Something like:
SELECT
    S.Value AS Id,
    -- Number1..Number7 have mutually exclusive values
    MAX(CASE WHEN N.RowNum = 1 THEN N.Number END) AS Number1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN N.RowNum = 2 THEN N.Number END) AS Number2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN N.RowNum = 3 THEN N.Number END) AS Number3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN N.RowNum = 4 THEN N.Number END) AS Number4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN N.RowNum = 5 THEN N.Number END) AS Number5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN N.RowNum = 6 THEN N.Number END) AS Number6,
    MAX(CASE WHEN N.RowNum = 7 THEN N.Number END) AS Number7,
    -- Number8 is independent
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10) + 1 AS Number8
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100) S
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Use a randomizer to effectively permutate the numbers 1..25
    SELECT
        S2.value AS Number,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY R.Randomizer) AS RowNum
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 25) S2
    CROSS APPLY(
        --SELECT CHECKSUM(NEWID(), S.value, S2.value) AS Randomizer
        SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', CONCAT(NEWID(), S.value, S2.value)) AS Randomizer
    ) R
) N
GROUP BY S.Value
ORDER BY S.Value

I use the HASHBYTES() function above to generate a randomized based on NEWID(). The S.value and S2.value values have been included to avoid duplicate hash values for cases where SQL server sometimes applies the same NEWID() value multiple times in a query. (I have yet to find a clear definition of when this does or does not occur.)
I am not sure how much computational overhead HASHBYTES() adds, but the CHECKSUM() might also be a less-costly option at the cost of possible "less random" results. Although we really don't care about cryptographically secure randomness here, the 'MD5' hash algorithm selector could also be changed if needed.
Sample results (first 10 rows):



Id
Number1
Number2
Number3
Number4
Number5
Number6
Number7
Number8




1
1
24
15
6
3
19
23
5


2
13
10
15
11
22
21
9
1


3
22
4
13
15
23
20
9
1


4
5
14
23
25
13
10
12
10


5
6
5
1
9
17
14
7
6


6
5
25
10
3
13
12
7
5


7
2
25
19
20
1
14
8
9


8
1
9
13
22
24
17
7
10


9
1
18
23
19
10
15
7
2


10
2
9
12
1
5
14
19
7



Note that the Number8 column in rows 4, 5 and 6 duplicates an earlier value in the same row, but the values in columns Number1 through Number7 are distinct within each row.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

This will get you 7 distinct numbers between 1 and 25, and an 8th number between 1 and 10 not equal to the first 7 numbers.
   SELECT TOP(100) x3.*, N8 = (
                                 SELECT TOP(1) r.N
                                 FROM       core.rangeX(1,10,1) AS r
                                 WHERE    r.N NOT IN (N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7)
                                 ORDER BY NEWID()
                               )
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT
        N1 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=1,x2.N,NULL)),
        N2 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=2,x2.N,NULL)),
        N3 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=3,x2.N,NULL)),
        N4 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=4,x2.N,NULL)),
        N5 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=5,x2.N,NULL)),
        N6 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=6,x2.N,NULL)),
        N7 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=7,x2.N,NULL))
      FROM
      (
        SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), x1.N
        FROM
        (
          SELECT TOP(7) r.N
          FROM       core.rangeX(1,25,1) AS r
          ORDER BY   NEWID()
        ) AS x1
      ) AS x2
    ) x3;

This returns:

You can use a loop run this for each required row. Here's the final solution:
DECLARE @t TABLE (N1 TINYINT,N2 TINYINT,N3 TINYINT,N4 TINYINT,
                  N5 TINYINT,N6 TINYINT,N7 TINYINT,N8 TINYINT)
DECLARE @i INT = 1;

WHILE @i <= 5
BEGIN

  INSERT @t
  SELECT TOP(100) x3.*, N8 = (
                               SELECT TOP(1) r.N
                               FROM       core.rangeX(1,10,1) AS r
                               WHERE    r.N NOT IN (N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7)
                               ORDER BY NEWID()
                             )
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      N1 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=1,x2.N,NULL)),
      N2 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=2,x2.N,NULL)),
      N3 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=3,x2.N,NULL)),
      N4 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=4,x2.N,NULL)),
      N5 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=5,x2.N,NULL)),
      N6 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=6,x2.N,NULL)),
      N7 = MAX(IIF(x2.RN=7,x2.N,NULL))
    FROM
    (
      SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), x1.N
      FROM
      (
        SELECT TOP(7) r.N
        FROM       core.rangeX(1,25,1) AS r
        ORDER BY   NEWID()
      ) AS x1
    ) AS x2
  ) x3;

  SET @i+=1;
END

SELECT * FROM @t;

Returns:

NOTE: I am on a 2017 and don't have GENERATE_SERIES so I used my own function called RangeX (below).
CREATE   FUNCTION core.rangeX
(
  @Low  BIGINT,
  @High BIGINT,
  @Gap  BIGINT
)
/****************************************************************************************
[Purpose]:
 Creates a lazy, in-memory, forward-ordered sequence of up to 1,073,741,824 integers
 beginning with @Low and ending with @High (inclusive). RangeX is a pure, 100% set-based
 alternative to solving SQL problems using iterative methods such as loops, cursors and
 recursive CTEs. RangeX is based on Itzik Ben-Gan's getnums function for producing a
 sequence of integers and uses logic from Jeff Moden's fnTally function which includes a
 parameter for determining if the "row-number" (RN) should begin with 0 or 1.
 
 I used the name "RangeX" because it functions and performs almost identically to
 the Range function built into Python and Clojure. RANGE is a reserved SQL keyword so I 
 went with "RangeX". Functions/Algorithms developed using RangeX can be easilty ported
 over to Python, Clojure or any other programming language that leverages a lazy sequence.
 The two major differences between RangeX and the Python/Clojure versions are:
   1. RangeX is *Inclusive* where the other two are *Exclusive". range(0,3) in Python and
      Clojure return [0 1 2], core.RangeX(0,3) returns [0 1 2 3].
   2. RangeX has a fourth Parameter (@Row1) to determine if RN should begin with 0 or 1.

[Author]:
 Alan Burstein

[Compatibility]: 
 SQL Server 2008+

[Syntax]:
 SELECT r.RN, r.OP, r.DM, r.N, r.NOP
 FROM   core.RangeX(@Low,@High,@Gap) AS r;

[Parameters]:
 @Low  = BIGINT; The lowest  value for N.
 @High = BIGINT; The highest value for N.
 @Gap  = BIGINT; The distance between each N value.
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Revision History]:
 Rev 00.0 - 20140518 - Initial Development - AJB
 Rev 06.0 - 20240625 - Final redesign - AJB
*****************************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
WITH T(N) AS ( -- 90*90*90=729000, 729000*729000 = 531,441,000,000 Rows Total
 SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES
  (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
  (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
  (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
  (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
  (0),(0)) T(N)), -- 90 values
L(N)   AS (SELECT 1 FROM T CROSS JOIN T AS T2 CROSS JOIN T AS T3),
iTally AS (SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM L CROSS JOIN L AS L2)
SELECT TOP((@high-@low+1)/@gap+SIGN((@high-@low+1)%@gap))
  RN  = i.RN,
  OP  = o.OP,
  DM  = (i.RN-o.OP)/2,
  N   = @low+(i.RN-1)*@gap,
  NOP = @low+(o.OP-1)*@gap
FROM        iTally                                                  AS i
CROSS APPLY (VALUES((@high-@low+1)/@gap+SIGN((@high-@low+1)%@gap))) AS r(T)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(r.T-i.RN+1))                                    AS o(OP)
ORDER BY    RN;
GO

